# Is this possible to build Spark DataType manually from string?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to build Spark DataTypes manually from string depends on DataType of the column.
I've tried it in different ways like:

> ```
> dataType match {
>   case IntegerType => DataTypes.IntegerType(data.toInt)
> ```

But can't find the way to do it correctly. Is this possible? 
I need to compare value given me as string with the value in the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you already have a data structure but want a conversion of the data types according to Spark's `DataTypes`. I assume, there are no nested sequences or arrays.

```
object DataTypeUtil {

  def anyValueOfStringWithDataType(dataWithType: (String, DataType)): Any = {
    val dataType = dataWithType._2
    val data = dataWithType._1
    dataType match {
      case _: StringType => data
      case _: IntegerType => Integer.valueOf(data)
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
    }
  }

  def stringsToRows(values: Seq[String], dataTypes: Seq[DataType]): Row =
    Row.fromSeq(values.zip(dataTypes).map(anyValueOfStringWithDataType))

}
```

Comment: But wouldn't this Integer.valueOf(data) returns value just as Scala Integer and not the IntegerType?

Comment: Yes, it just returns any Scala type. The actual conversion from the Scala type to the Spark type is done within Row.fromSeq.